# SOLR terms autocomplete returns not all words

Tags: solr

I have a problem with SOLR terms.

My query is

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/terms?terms=true&terms.lower.incl=false&indent=true&wt=json&terms.fl=a_dm_testo&terms.prefix=quel
```

Response from SOLR

```
{"responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0},
  "terms":{
    "a_dm_testo":[
      "quell",1]}}
```

But this field in SOLR contains much more words with prefix "quel":

quello - 2
quelle - 1
quella - 1
....

I don`t understand what is wrong, can anybody help me?

Comment: I found the problem in my schema.xml so this problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was with settings of schema.xml. When I rolled back to default "text_general" settings in schema.xml my problem was resolved.

Comment: Which settings? Could you tell us so that people who come here in future can benefit?

Comment: Sorry but I arledy removed this settings, but if you will use default settings for "text_general" from schema.xml all will be fine. When I rolled back to standart "text_general" settings my problem was resolved.